# AVPlayer auto play when enter to foreground from background using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, rx-swift

I have a video and play in ViewController.
But when I enter to background and then back to foreground, the video sometimes pause.
Have any idea let code add notification to know the user back to foreground and make the video auto playing.
Thanks.

```
extension UIViewController: AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate {

private func playVideo(url: URL, completeHandler: @escaping () -> Void) -> Void {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    let vc = AVPlayerViewController.init()
    vc.videoGravity = "AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill"
    vc.showsPlaybackControls = false
    vc.player = player

    // add child view controller
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    // constraints
    vc.view.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        make.left.equalToSuperview()
        make.right.equalToSuperview()
    }
    // end play
    _ = NotificationCenter.default.rx
    .notification(NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
    .takeUntil(self.rx.deallocated)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            for vc in self?.childViewControllers ?? [] {
                if vc is AVPlayerViewController {
                    vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    vc.removeFromParentViewController()
                }
            }
            completeHandler()
        })

    vc.player?.play()

}
}
```

Comment: Make sure Background Modes enable

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have callbacks exactly for that purpose in `UIApplicatonDelegate` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate

- `applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`
- `func applicationWillEnterForeground(UIApplication)`

So you will have to pause/resume video from those callback methods.